# AngularJS, template EJS, Can't convert string in JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, ejs

I have a problem with convert string on JSON.parse().
I sended the variable ID by:

```
router.get('/edit/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('product/edit', { title: 'Express', id: req.params.id });
});
```

later i took him here

```
ng-init="init('<%= id %>')">
```

But its string, now i want to convert it on JSON.parse in controller

```
$scope.init = function (id) {
  $scope.product.id = JSON.parse(id);
  $scope.loadProducts()
}
```

And i have error in console:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: it's not a valid JSON... check the value of `id`

Comment: In ID is value "1498205963917", so I can't do JSON.parse() because It's not valid JSON yes?

Comment: use `$scope.product.id = id;` or `$scope.product.id = Number(id);`

Comment: Why would you need to use JSON.parse with `"1498205963917"`? Do you want convert it to a number? Use `parseInt` or `+id`.

Comment: +id? Can you expand?

Comment: Try `+"1498205963917"` in console.